# How to print two arrays side by side in angular template?

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays, angular

**strong text**

I have two arrays that i want to print next to each other in angular template.I tried using ng for inside div and span but im not getting desired output.
A=[1,2,3,4]
B=[A,B,C,D]

Actual Result using ngFor using div and span :

Using Div :

1

2

3

4

A

B

C

D

Using Span:1 2 3 4 A B C D

desired output:

1 A

2 B

3 C

4 D

I want to get result like above please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

just use  "index" for the second array

```
<div *ngFor="let item of a;let i=index>
{{item}}{{b[i]}}
</div>
```

Comment: there was an error in the *ngFor (just corrected) is *ngFor="let item **of** a...

Answer (score 1):

You may also consider creating a 2D array using `.map()` and then using resultant array with `*ngFor`:

**JS:**

```
let A = [1, 2, 3, 4];
let B = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'];
let C = A.map((v, i) => [v, B[i]]);
```

**HTML:**

```
<div *ngFor="let item in C">
    {{item[0]}} {{item[1]}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

*ngFor gives an option to get index of the array. Also, several other exported values can be used. Refer to [Angular Documentation](https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf) for more details.

**Solution:**

```
<div *ngFor="let value of firstArray; let i = index">{{value}} {{secondArray[i]}}</div>
```